# How to make AJAX loaded content affected by parent page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This problem has bugged me for some time.. If I load something in through AJAX, I have to have the javascript inside the AJAX loaded file (or call an external JS).

**How can I make AJAX loaded content be controlled by the master or parent page??**

I'd like to take control of all links to pass them through javascript (jquery) and do some fun stuff, but I don't really want to make it an external JS and use $.getScript. I just want my main javascript to be able to work with ajax loaded content.

(Here's an example)

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // Fun stuff
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind your method, using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), to the closest parent container that **isn't** replaced. For example:

```
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      // Fun stuff
    })
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Cool beans. I tried some variation of this but I didn't think to process it using the selector arg and attaching to an upper node. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your full example? After you load the content you want trough AJAX you can control the content by Javascript after you have appended it to the DOM.

For example:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#newContent').hide().html(data)
    .find('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```